# Alarm Notification is silent but shouldn't

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

In my creation of my notification I use the category ALARM and the highest priority.

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setWhen(alarmTime)                    .setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_accent))
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

But still, on my HTC One Max currently running Android 5.0.1, whenever the user silences the phone no sound is played EVEN though in the setup of volumes, alarms are set to still have a loud sound. (it's a dialog on HTC phones with three silders: one for ringtone, one for music&video and one for alarms).

Is there any way to really make sure that the alarm is played for the user?

Thanks!

Comment: have you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

Set Alarm Permission in your Manifest

[SET_ALARM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: I am not setting an alarm... don't know exactly what this should do. Please explain. I have a notification set up as shown above...

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your manifest, and whatever Broadcast Receiver you are using.
Most likely, you have a typo in either place, or another possibility is another application having the same or higher priority over the same receiver.

Comment: This has nothing to do with broadcast receivers... I get my Intent, of course. I just want the sound of the notification not to be silenced...